# machine.config' is denied

Tags: .net, iis-6, machine.config

My application is running on `windows server 2000` and `IIS 6`.
Up until this morning the application was working fine. But now I'm getting the error below:

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 0 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: are the automatic updates enabled on the server? Any changes in server or the network on which the server lies? contact your hosting company...

Comment: Windows 2000 ships IIS 5, so I wonder what exactly is the platform you use. Besides Windows 2000 (IIS 5) and Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) are all end of life. You must migrate to a newer Windows release right now (even in 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Check that the account which the application pool is running under has access to

```
'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config'
```

The permissions may have changed if the user account was updated or .NET was updated

Comment: To view effective permissions on files and folders. Open Windows Explorer, and then locate the file or folder for which you want to view effective permissions. Right-click the file or folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab. Click Advanced, click the Effective Permissions tab, and then click Select. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc771586.aspx